# Rotating the main Body in X but keeping the child transform intact

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a simple question that somehow i cannot figuring.

so basically i have this:[image]

It just a simple Unity cube and sphere. Nothing fancy.

Currently if i rotate the bigger cube in X, Y and Z, of course the yellow sphere will follow. 
because it is a child of the bigger cube
like this;

[image]

But what I would like to have is; to make the yellow sphere stay in place, when the bigger cube is rotating in X axis;
like this:

[image]

I do want to keep the Child's transformation when the bigger cube is rotating in Y and Z though.
Like this one;

[image]

I use Transform.TransformPoint. But still no luck.

I do attached this script to the Yellow Sphere., It holds yellow sphere but also holding its position when the Bigger cube is rotating in Y&Z(which i dont want too).

```
public class lockedPosition : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform target;
    private Vector3 debug;
    public Vector3 offset;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        debug = transform.position;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        this.transform.position = debug + offset;
    }
}
```

any pointer on this will be awesome! :D
Thankss!! ^^,

Comment: I'm not sure it is possible.  I think what you are saying is the ball x value to always be the same and just change the y and z value of the ball.  But what happens if the cube is rotated 180 degrees?  The cube has an origin (0,0,0).  So are you saying the ball should always be along a vector from the origin of the cube with the same y-z angle (rotate around x)?

Answer (score 0):

you can checkout this answer. I hope this might be able to do the trick for you.
You can maybe use the transform.rotation.x or something to hold your child objects position while the parent is rotating in x axis.
I hope this works out for you.
Happy coding :)

[Setting a child object to not rotate](https://answers.unity.com/questions/423031/how-do-i-set-a-child-object-to-not-rotate-if-the-p.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the behaviour parent/children used in Unity. It can be very useful but in your case it's a problem. The easiest solution should be to remove the sphere from the cube's childs so it will not be affected by the transform changes (position, rotation and scale) of its parents.

If you don't have the choice, one solution is to use constraints. You can add a **PositionConstraint** and/or **RotationConstraint** script to your sphere's gameObject.

Create an empty gameObject which is just used to maintain the constraint and add a constraint with this transform and it will do the job, even in edit mode.
Place the empty object where you want the sphere to stay.

[image: PositionAndRotationConstraint]

Comment: Hi @AlexAR thank you for answering..
 Hmmm I am not sure how to do this., but when i put the position constraint it somehow only rotating around. and doesnt do what i want.
Perhaps you can give me a bit of pointer with the Contrains Setting ?

Comment: Add the position constraint to the sphere. Create an empty game object and place it at the sphere position. Add a source in the position constraint and drag the empty game object as you can see on the screenshot. Click on activate and lock the position in the constraint settings. Now if you move the bigger cube, the sphere can't move but rotate on itself. So if you want to block also the rotation add the Rotation Constraint and do the same : add empty game object in source, lock the rotation and activate.

Comment: ., Alright.,  i did do it like your pointer.
It does lock the sphere in place when i rotate the X-axis of the BigCube.
But it also lock the sphere if i rotate the Y&Z axis of the BigCube.
I do however need the sphere to act like a child behaviour when rotating the Y&Z.

I try to uncheck the "FreezePosition Axes" of X in the Position Constraint, but it just orbiting between the Big Cube and the empty game Object.